# How to "properly" send sms when call is received?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have an Android **Service** listen for an incoming phone call and when one does occur, grab the incoming number and text it a message.

In my service I have made a **PhoneStateListener:**

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d(TAG, "Phone: Idle");
            break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.d(TAG, "Phone: Ringing.");
                Log.i(TAG, "Incoming call from: " + incomingNumber);
                sendSms();
            break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d(TAG, "Phone: Off Hook");
            break;
        }
    }
};
tManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

My **sendSms()** function is as follows:

```
private void sendSms()
{
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    wakeLock.acquire();
    Log.d(TAG, "Wake Lock Acquired!");

    if (getMessageContent(getInformStatus()).length() > 160)
    {
        ArrayList<String> messagelist = manager.divideMessage(getMessageContent(getInformStatus()));

        manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(getReturnAddress(), null, messagelist, null, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "Multipart Text Message Sent!");
    }
    else
    {
        manager.sendTextMessage(getReturnAddress(), null, getMessageContent(getInformStatus()), sentPI, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "Text Message Sent!");
    }

    wakeLock.release();
    Log.d(TAG, "Wake Lock Released!");
}
```

I even have an **SMS_SENT** Broadcast Receiver to check if the text message sent out correctly that will recall the sendSms() function if it did not sent for whatever reason:

```
resend = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Log.e(TAG, "Text did NOT send (GENERIC_FAILURE)");
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resend");
                sendSms();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Log.e(TAG, "Text did NOT send (NO_SERVICE)");
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resend");
                sendSms();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Log.e(TAG, "Text did NOT send (RADIO_OFF)");
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resend");
                sendSms();
            break;
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(resend, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"));
```

This works on my phone fine, however on other people's phones it likes to sometimes toggle back and forth between **RINGING** and **IDLE** in the PhoneStateListener a few times before "sending"..  The phone actually says that the application is trying to **send multiple text messages** and asks the user if that is okay.  When they click yes, it just asks again.

To make it better, it *never* actually sends the text message either..

On another phone, it doesn't do this at all..  The other phone will go through the motions and the **logcat** is identical to mine.. It actually says it sends, but the recipient never *gets* the SMS..

It is suppose to be an auto-response service of sorts and I wanted to try and make it work on at least Froyo, Gingerbread, and Ice Cream Sandwich..

By the way, it works 100% on my:
  Galaxy Nexus (toro) (Android 4.0.3)
  Droid 1 (sholes) (Android 2.3.7)
  HTC Thunderbolt (mecha) (Android 2.3.7)

However, if it's my friend's:
  Nexus S 4G (crespo4g) (Android 4.0.3)
    or my other friend's
  Galaxy Nexus (toro) (Android 4.0.3)

It does **not** work..

What I really don't understand is that it doesn't work with my friend with the exact same phone as me..

I feel like this code implementation is a hit or miss and was wondering if anyone had some **insight** to help out.

Appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old question, but this question is intriguing! Did you ever find out why the sms wasn't bring sent? Could it be because you can't send a sms during a call??

Comment: Also, were all phones using GSM? Also, how do you know the message was sent? As I see you're not checking for a ACTIVITY.RESULT_OK in your broadcast receiver......

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.  What I ended up doing is putting a **Handler** that called a **Runnable** 30 seconds after the phone call was initially received..  This gave the phone time to finish the phone call (assuming it was in your pocket) and then *cleanly* send the text message..

I hope this is the only issues I was having, but it seems to work on my friends Galaxy Nexus (toro) now..

Hope this helps anyone else wondering about this..

Cheers!